# Prove the sequence $\frac{nz}{n+1} + \frac{3}{n}$ converges uniformly to $z$ on $|z| \leq R|$ for all $R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

My attempt:

Given any $\epsilon > 0$,
\begin{align}
\sup_{|z| \leq R}\, 
\biggl\lvert \frac{nz}{n+1} +\frac{3}{n} - z \biggr\rvert 
&= \sup_{|z| \leq R}\, 
\biggl\lvert \frac{nz-nz-z}{n+1} + \frac{3}{n} \biggr\rvert \\
&= \sup_{|z| \leq R}\, 
\biggl\lvert \frac{-z}{n+1}+\frac{3}{n} \biggr\rvert \\
&\leq \frac{R}{n+1} + \frac{3}{n} \\
&< \frac{3}{n}.
\end{align}
Choose $N(\epsilon) = \bigl\lceil \frac{3}{\epsilon} \bigr\rceil$.
Then $\frac{3}{n} < \epsilon$. Hence, proved.

I want to make sure that my proof is valid and also will it matter if we take the ceiling function of $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ or not.

Comment: Where does that $\frac3n$ come from?

Comment: my mistake, I didn't type the correct sequence in first place. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not correct, because you wrote that $\frac R{n+1}+\frac3n<\frac3n$, which is false.

You have$$\frac R{n+1}+\frac3n<\frac Rn+\frac3n=\frac{R+3}n.$$ So, take$$N(\varepsilon)=\left\lceil\frac{R+3}\varepsilon\right\rceil.$$